# NEO4J Exception On record fetching

Tags: database, neo4j, nosql

A simple Neo4j query is giving me a `StackOverFlowError`.

The query is

`match(n:StudentApplicationGraph) with n.applicationNo as app, count(n.applicationNo) as count where count>1 return app, count limit 25;`

Underneath are the logs

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3777)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4602)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4602)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4602)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4568)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4604)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4602)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Start.match(Pattern.java:3461)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.search(Matcher.java:1248)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.find(Matcher.java:664)
at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2549)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2501)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2455)
at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2940)
at org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.KernelException.<init>(KernelException.java:38)
at org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.EntityNotFoundException.<init>(EntityNotFoundException.java:31)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.getNodeById(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:312)
at org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.internal.GraphDatabaseCypherService.getNodeById(GraphDatabaseCypherService.java:70)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.spi.v3_1.TransactionBoundQueryContext$NodeOperations.getById(TransactionBoundQueryContext.scala:342)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.spi.v3_1.TransactionBoundQueryContext$$anonfun$getNodesByLabel$1.apply(TransactionBoundQueryContext.scala:284)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.spi.v3_1.TransactionBoundQueryContext$$anonfun$getNodesByLabel$1.apply(TransactionBoundQueryContext.scala:284)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_1.helpers.JavaConversionSupport$$anon$5.fetchNext(JavaConversionSupport.scala:60)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_1.helpers.JavaConversionSupport$$anon$5.fetchNext(JavaConversionSupport.scala:63)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_1.helpers.JavaConversionSupport$$anon$5.fetchNext(JavaConversionSupport.scala:63)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_1.helpers.JavaConversionSupport$$anon$5.fetchNext(JavaConversionSupport.scala:63)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_1.helpers.JavaConversionSupport$$anon$5.fetchNext(JavaConversionSupport.scala:63)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_1.helpers.JavaConversionSupport$$anon$5.fetchNext(JavaConversionSupport.scala:63)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_1.helpers.JavaConversionSupport$$anon$5.fetchNext(JavaConversionSupport.scala:63)
```

Last line keeps on repeating until stack over flow.

Thank you in advance

Comment: can you provide sample data?
I was unable to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I later found out that there was a relation which was corrupted and because of that the self-referring relation consumed all the memory and this issue occurred.